# The layout is overlapping after running app in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I created a profile layout and in XML file it looks like this :

[image]

but, when I run my project, it looks like this :
[image]

This is my XML code if it helps :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Profile.ProfileFragment"
    android:background="@drawable/main_activity">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_photo"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/black"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.164" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonFollow"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/buton_follow"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
        android:text="Follow"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.481"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_photo"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui_bold"
        android:text="Calin Alexandra"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonFollow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
        android:text="Cook lover"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.471"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/display_name"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/website"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
        android:text="www.cook.ro"
        android:textColor="@color/link_blue"

        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPosts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
        android:text="250"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.29"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.472" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPosts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
        android:text="Posts"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPosts" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFollowers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
        android:text="300"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.471" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textFollowers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
        android:text="Followers"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textFollowing"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.606"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textPosts"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFollowers" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFollowing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="112dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
        android:text="400"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.471" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textFollowing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
        android:text="Following"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFollowing" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textEditProfile"
        android:layout_width="198dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_user_pass"
        android:text="Edit your profile"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textFollowers"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buton_mesaj"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_message"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.855"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.02" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buton_setari"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_settings"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.111"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buton_mesaj"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.02" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="alecalin36"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buton_mesaj"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.062"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.019" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textFollowers">

    </GridView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to mention that all the items(TextView, Button) have been added only with drag and drop and after that, I connected them to edges and items around to stay in the same place but unfortunately this is not happening.

Also, I did the same thing with my Login layout and I don't have any problem.
[image]

Does this problem have to do with the fact that the username, description, etc from the second photo are taken from firebase?? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to constrain top of tvPosts,tvFollowers,tvFollowing to bottom of website

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".Profile.ProfileFragment"
  android:background="@drawable/main_activity">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
      android:id="@+id/profile_photo"
      android:layout_width="80dp"
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      app:civ_border_color="@color/black"
      app:civ_border_width="2dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.164" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
      android:id="@+id/buttonFollow"
      android:layout_width="83dp"
      android:layout_height="31dp"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:background="@drawable/buton_follow"
      android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
      android:text="Follow"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textSize="15dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.481"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_photo"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/display_name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui_bold"
      android:text="Calin Alexandra"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:textSize="25sp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonFollow" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/description"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
      android:text="Cook lover"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:textSize="16sp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.471"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/display_name"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/website"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
      android:text="www.cook.ro"
      android:textColor="@color/link_blue"

      android:textSize="16sp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvPosts"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
      android:text="250"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.29"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/website"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.472" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textPosts"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
      android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
      android:text="Posts"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:textSize="12sp"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvPosts"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tvPosts"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPosts" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvFollowers"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
      android:text="300"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/website"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.471" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textFollowers"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
      android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
      android:text="Followers"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:textSize="12sp"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvFollowers"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tvFollowers"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFollowers" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvFollowing"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginEnd="112dp"
      android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
      android:text="400"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/website"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.471" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textFollowing"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
      android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
      android:text="Following"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:textSize="12sp"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvFollowing"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tvFollowing"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFollowing" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textEditProfile"
      android:layout_width="198dp"
      android:layout_height="22dp"
      android:background="@drawable/text_user_pass"
      android:text="Edit your profile"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:textSize="14sp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textFollowers"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054"
      android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
      android:id="@+id/buton_mesaj"
      android:layout_width="31dp"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:background="@drawable/ic_message"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.855"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.02" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
      android:id="@+id/buton_setari"
      android:layout_width="31dp"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:background="@drawable/ic_settings"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.111"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buton_mesaj"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.02" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/username"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="alecalin36"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:textSize="15sp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buton_mesaj"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.062"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.019" />

    <GridView
      android:id="@+id/gridView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
      android:numColumns="3"
      android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
      android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textFollowers">

    </GridView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks you,  that was the problem. I thought that I connected them to Top edge and all thr other edges but it seems that I missed some.